# sinch send message to the same id as the current client id - to build a group chat

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api

Hi am currently trying to adapt my sinch parse messaging app to implement a group chat , but using this schema

```
  startSinchClient(intent.getStringExtra("group_conversation_id"));
```

and send messages to the same group_conversation_id so that all user connecting to the sinch using the same group_id can recieve incoming messages

current i dont get any error while the message doesnt not call on the `onMessageSent`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send message to your self via Sinch.

And sinch is not providing any functionality like group chat, however you can use broadcast message, which is same as broadcast message in whatsapp.